# sage paypal US Shipping country issue

Tags: paypal, opayo

I am facing issue when select card pay-pal. IT returns the error
"pay pal returned error.Please select other card".Can anyone help. It return when customer billing country is USA or United States.

Comment: Kindly anyone look in to this issue . I will be very thank full to you .

Answer (score 0):

Pay Pal do put in validation relating to the State, City and ZIP. If there is a mismatch then an error can be returned.

Check the combination for city, state and zip is correct.